# Adding a pop-up box in the middle of the screen when fields are left blank

Tags: javascript, html, css, popupwindow

This so far will add the word empty to fields left blank, but i need to add a pop-up at the top-middle of the screen stating "please fill in all fields before submitting" in its own custom box i can change using css to style it.

this seems like a very simple thing to do although i just cant find out how.

if the following code is horrible its what has been given to me for the exercise, with zero documentation on how to perform the task.

do i need to create a div for the pop up box and a function to execute it? by calling the fuction in the if statement.

i apologies if i have been vague or made no sense as this is still very new to me (im sure thats obvious haha)

thanksguys!

```
var requiredFields = [ "firstname", "lastname", "email", "message" ];

function checkContactForm() {
  var theForm = document.forms[ 0 ];

  for ( var i in requiredFields ) {
    var fieldName = requiredFields[ i ];

    if ( !theForm[ fieldName ].value || theForm[ fieldName ].value == "Error" ) {
      theForm[ fieldName ].style.color = "#f66";
      theForm[ fieldName ].value = "Error";


      var emptyFields = true; 
    } 
  }

  if ( !emptyFields ) { theForm.submit(); }
  }

 function resetField( theField ) {
    if ( theField.value == "Error" ) {
    theField.value = "";
  }
    theField.style.color = "#000";
  }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using jQuery; are jQuery answers really appropriate for you? This is quite possible in plain JavaScript as well.

Comment: apologies for adding the jQuery, that was for the previous part of this assignment, this is just JavaScript. any info on doing this is plain JavaScript would be amazing

Comment: No apology necessary; just trying to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Incidentally, how much of the above are you allowed to change? It's not necessarily 'horrible,' but it's not the way I'd personally attempt to address the requirements.

Comment: honestly i would say none, as its just a mock form for us to add the popup to.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a jquery ui .dialog like: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/aL14evyk/

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```